# I have used google face api and it tracks face well but i want to get the x,y coordinates related to mobile actual screen

Tags: android

Face movement detection whether it moves up,down,right or left using front camera in android

Tried google face api but it gives coordinates in pixels terms maybe

any help would be life saving

Comment: coordinates of mobile screen is also measured in pixels

Comment: You use google API or google face detector? what have you used API library of google dace API? please clear ask us. so we are giving your perfect answer of your question ...